# Remove class from list item and add a class to a different list item using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have a list where a list item is set to active. On page load, I want this active to be taken off and added to another list item. I am trying this on a fiddle but it happen as I want it to. What am I doing wrong? Fiddle here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmnovu06/) 
Code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li id="stock2"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#stock">Stock</a></li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
var selector = '.nav li';
var stockv = 'stock';
if(stockv != ''){

$(selector).removeClass('active');
$('#stock2').addClass('active');
$('#stock2').addClass('area-expanded="true"');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st:** you should be sure to include jquery .. to include jquery add the next line into `<head></head>` or before `</body>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2nd:** you have a syntax error in last line  `});` should be `};`

```
var selector = '.nav li.active'; // add .active here
var stockv = 'stock';
if(stockv !== ''){
   $(selector).removeClass('active');
   $('#stock2').addClass('active');
   //$('#stock2').addClass('area-expanded="true"');
};                          //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/gmnovu06/1/)

Final answer ( to click another tab on bootstrap tabs)

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('a[href="#stock"]').tab('show');
});
```

[**Demo Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/DTcHh/20519/)

Comment: Thanks, this works in your fiddle, I changed it accordingly in mine, but it doesn't change. Strange

Comment: @YohanBlake I update my answer with how to include jquery .. and to include jquery in jsfiddle  you have gear icon on top of your right hand side in javascript section  click it and choose jquery

Comment: @YohanBlake to be sure jquery included or not .. if you get an error in console say  ($ is not defined) .. that mean jquery not included

Comment: thanks for this, it works on the fiddle. But I'm trying to add this to my php file but it fails. I added the jquery code in script tags just before the ul tags and included jquery too

Comment: @YohanBlake sorry answer updated with new script src .. check it here https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/gmnovu06/3/

Comment: you got error of ($ is not defined)? while you already include jquery??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111813/discussion-between-yohan-blake-and-mohamed-yousef).